# Parsing license file with regex

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I want to parse a license file which somehow has contents like this.

> COMPONENTS="A0000 B0000 G0000"

The quotation marks are necessarily there in the file to mark start and end to components in a package. I've tested combinations on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/inQcMG/1) but that does not solve the problem

The regex `("?(?<components>\w+)*\s?"?)` works for the string "A0000 B0000 G0000" and returns me individual values of components that I need: A0000 , B0000 and so on

But when I test  `(COMPONENTS|PACKAGES)=("?(?<components>\w+)\s?"?)` , the block fails to return these values and returns only the first one which is A0000.

I need help with extracting all those individual values. Please help.

Comment: Do you mean you want something like [`(?:\G(?!^)\s+|(?:COMPONENTS|PACKAGES)=")\K[^\s"]+`](https://regex101.com/r/2vki7C/1)?

Comment: If the quotes are required why do you put a '?' quantifier after them? Also, your second regex looks for \w+ followed by \s, but does not repeat that pattern, so it's no wonder it would only capture a single field.

Comment: How does `PACKAGES=...` come into this?  Are there also the same kinds of lines for that? How are they related to `COMPONENTS` lines, or are they completely independent?

Comment: Pranay, when you tagged the question with `perl` tag, did you mean the Perl 5 language or any specific option in the language you are using (like R)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your solution worked. I couldn't understand why it would not replicate to other parts of the file if preceding and succeeding lines are included in the regex. I included `perl` in the tag because the regex was to be written for Perl language.

Comment: @zdim There are similar kinds of lines for that. `PACKAGES=` succeeds `COMPONENTS=` very often. The outputs desired are their values.

Comment: @DavidO there's a '?' after the quotes because values like `B0000` do not have them but they are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my solution worked for you, I am posting an answer:

```
(?:\G(?!^)\s+|(?:COMPONENTS|PACKAGES)=")\K[^\s"]+
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:\G(?!^)\s+|(?:COMPONENTS|PACKAGES)=")` - either of the two alternatives:
- `\G(?!^)\s+` - end of the previous match (`\G` matches either the start of a line/string or the end of the previous match, so `(?!^)` "subtracts" the start of string position) and 1+ whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `(?:COMPONENTS|PACKAGES)=` - either `COMPONENTS=` or `PACKAGES=`
- `\K` - match reset operator (discarding the currently matched text)
- `[^\s"]+` - 1 or more chars other than whitespace and double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

I may be misunderstanding the problem but what about the simple

```
my %result;
while (<$fh>) {
    my ($type, $components) = /(\w+)\s*=\s*"([^"]+)/;
    push @{$result{$type}}, split ' ', $components;      # all in one arrayref
    #push @{$result{$type}}, [ split ' ', $components ]; # or as separate ones
}
```

This expects multiple lines with `COMPONENTS` and/or `PACKAGES` (or any other leading key words really), and assumes that they are unrelated to each other and so need be stored separately.

Please clarify if the assumptions are wrong.

The code above creates the hash

```
(
    COMPONENTS => [ 'A0000', 'B0000', 'G0000', ... ],
    PACKAGES   => [ ... ],
)
```

where `[ ... ]` is an arrayref with components from all lines for that keyword.

Or, if the commented-out line in the code is used instead of the one above it,

```
(
    COMPONENTS => [ ['A0000', 'B0000', 'G0000'], [ ... ], ... ],
    PACKAGES   => [ [ ... ], [ ... ], ... ],
)
```

where `[ ... ]` are arrayrefs with components from a line, which are all stored in an arrayref which is the value for a key. So here components for each line are stored separately, rather than all being in one arrayref as in the previous case.

If there are any other words before `=` they are stored as their own keys, with their own arrayref(s) with data from those lines.

---

**Update** to clarifications

Since quotes may or may not be there make the first one optional with `?`

```
/(\w+)\s*=\s*"?[^"]+)/;
```

while the trailing one need not be handled since the rest of data need be matched

Comment: @ikegami  Yes, that seems far more likely, thank you.  Edited

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest a different approach here. Your regex pattern is getting complicated, and that's not a great idea.

The core of your problem is that to make a repeating match you're matching the prefix text too, and obviously that can only match once.

But rather than trying to make your regex pattern even more complicated, the answer is to approach the problem differently.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %conf = do { local $/; <DATA> } =~ m/ (\w+) =" ([^"]+) " /xg; 
print Dumper \%conf; 

__DATA__
COMPONENTS="A0000 B0000 G0000"
PACKAGES="C0000 D0000 E0000"
```

This creates a data structure.

```
$VAR1 = {
          'COMPONENTS' => 'A0000 B0000 G0000',
          'PACKAGES' => 'C0000 D0000 E0000'
        };
```

If you want the values separately.

```
$_ = [split] for values %conf;
print Dumper \%conf;
```

This is functionally equivalent to this.

```
foreach my $key ( keys %conf ) {

  #split the value on whitespace.
  my @stuff = split ' ', $conf{$key};

  #replace it with your array. 
  $conf{$key} = \@stuff;
```

}

Which produces

```
$VAR1 = {
          'PACKAGES' => [
                          'C0000',
                          'D0000',
                          'E0000'
                        ],
          'COMPONENTS' => [
                            'A0000',
                            'B0000',
                            'G0000'
                          ]
        };
```

So now you can write this.

```
foreach my $value ( @{$conf{'COMPONENTS'}} ) { 
    print $value,"\n";
}
```

Comment: I hope you agree with my edit of your answer. I may have been overly picky this time. You're very welcome to roll it back if you disagree with me.

Comment: Basically I wanted to have both the values like how many components in a package because the file is written as such. I thought of writing a single regex because there are multiple sets of such couplings where there might be some capturing groups that are optional. I used some of your answer to split them into different regex.